# rails - how do I display many to many data model created with many to many association model in the ui?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a recipe, ingredient, Ingredient_Recipe models

recipe has

```
has_many :ingredient_recipes
has_many :Ingredients, :through => :RecipeIngredient
```

ingredient has

```
has_many :ingredient_recipes
has_many :Recipes, :through => :RecipeIngredient
```

Ingredient_Recipe has

```
belongs_to :recipes
belongs_to :ingredients
```

in my ui this doenst work anymore

```
<% @recipe.ingredients.each do |ingredient| %>
```

EDIT

```
  ActionView::Template::Error (uninitialized constant Recipe::Ingredients):  
97:                       </td>
98:                     <tr>
99:                       <td >
100:                         <% @recipe.ingredients.each do |ingredient| %>
101:                             ingredient.name
102:                         <% end %>
103:                       </td >
```

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
has_many :Ingredients, :through => :RecipeIngredient
```

to

```
has_many :ingredients, :through => :ingredient_recipes
```

Don't capitalise :ingredients, and :through needs to reference the association you're going through rather than the model.

For :recipes:

```
has_many :recipes, :through => :ingredient_recipes
```

Comment: Thanks. Now I get -  Could not find the association :RecipeIngredient in model Recipe on row  <% @recipe.ingredients.each do |ingredient| %> (also when debugging I see @associationHAsh=Empty Hash)

Comment: doing the obvious and changing it to IngredientRecipe I receive a couldnt evaluate message

Comment: You should be using IngredientRecipie as that's the rails conventions.  Make sure to stick with the conventions.  Try that and see if you get an error.  If you do it'll be something else.

Comment: Please post full error message text, "couldn't evaluate" doesn't have enough info for us to diagnose, plus the controller lines where it's happening.

Comment: Thanks for your time I keep getting then - Expected D:/path.../ingredient_recipe.rb to define IngredientRecipe (my association class is defined class Ingredient_Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base)

Comment: Your model should be defined as IngredientRecipe, not Ingredient_Recipe.